# How can we integrate identityserver4 and web api in the same project(port) instead of creating different projects for each?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

Couldn't configure the identityserver 4 authorization and bearer token authentication middleware in the same project.

Comment: what is wrong in this question -- the title or the body? what do you really want to combine? the second one is clear -- it's bearer token authentication middleware, but what's the first? is that identityserver middleware `services.AddIdentityServer()`, or just oidc auth middleware for Identityserver `services.AddAuthentication.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>{//options for idsrv auth})` to secure your MVC app?

Answer (score 8):

It is now a built-in feature of Identityserver. Added with [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/pull/3028) PR.

```cs
services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
```

And [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/host/LocalApiController.cs#L13) is an official example of a protected API.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you make API and Identity Server in separate apps. This makes it a lot easier to maintain.

Identity server provides you the authentication against your clients/API's. The database operations , the business logic should be handled by your clients/APIs . So keep them in separate apps should be a better choice .

If you insist on making them in single project , you can click [here](https://damienbod.com/2016/10/01/identityserver4-webapi-and-angular2-in-a-single-asp-net-core-project/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53720646/5751404) for code samples.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't.

The thing is that your authentication and your application are totally different services, with different scopes, and you should make them different.

This goes with Separation of Concern : if you want to change your auth service later, you won't have to modify your whole application.